# Excel Formula updated to clear out the zeros and sort

Tags: excel, formula

For the formula below do you know of any way formula could be updated so  that the sheet can automatic sort by the qty so the zeros or blanks rows would not be shown

```
=IF(OR(G13="",Input!G13<=0),"",Input!H13)
```

Comment: Sorting doesn't hide rows, it just reorders them. Have you tried using an autofilter to hide rows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you hover your cursor over the excel tag you'll see that it directs questions about Excel formulas to another site in the Stack Exchange family: [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).